# Calling oracle stored procedure repeatedly

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

Is it a good practice to call a stored procedure again and again inside a foreach loop to insert data into an Oracle table? Or is there an alternate way to do this?

I have the following procedure:

```
procedure proc1 (id     in  varchar2,
                 level  in  varchar2,
                 title  in  varchar2, 
                 p_id   in  varchar2, 
                 url    in  varchar2)
```

This is the code calling it:

```
foreach (var c in xDoc.Descendants("cat"))
{
    // call store procedure provide all values

    foreach (var a in xDoc.Descendants("abc"))
    {
        // call store procedure provide values

        foreach (var d in xDoc.Descendants("def"))
        {
            // call stored procedure provide values
        }
     }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like it would probably be a bad idea, but without a clear understanding of what you are trying to accomplish I can't offer advice. Can you explain a little bit about what you are doing?

Comment: @wweicker - I am trying to extract data from each foreach loop and enter that data to oracle table. Example: First loop gives 5 values:"1, 2, Null, Null, Null) second loop gives (1, 2, 3, Null, Null) third loop gives(1, 2, 3, 4, 5). And i need the values in this order only.

Comment: you want to insert data into an Oracle table in each iteration of your inner loop?

Comment: @wweicker- Yes and outter loop also. Like first loop will have 1, 2, 3, null, null.. Second loop will get one value from first loop 1, 4, 5, 5, null and do the insert. And so on third loop will get one value from second loop and do the insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally architect the Stored Procedure to give you the table that you want so that you only have to call it once. Calling the procedure multiple times like this is horribly inefficient because the database is generating a result set multiple times and you have the network overhead. If you create the procedure to return the table that you need, instead of bits and pieces of it, you can call the procedure once and iterate through the table with the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using ODP.NET, you can use [array binding](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html) to call your procedure **multiple times during a single database round-trip**. You pretty much bind your parameters as you normally would, except you assign an array (instead of just one value) to `OracleParameter.Value` and set `OracleCommand.ArrayBindCount` accordingly.

Let me give you a simplified example and I'm sure you won't have trouble adapting it to your needs...

Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_INSERT (ID IN NUMBER) AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(ID);
END TEST_INSERT;
```

C#:

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection("your connection string")) {

    conn.Open();

    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "TEST_INSERT";
    var param = cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleDbType.Int32, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);

    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    param.Value = arr;
    cmd.ArrayBindCount = arr.Length;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

After this piece of code executes, the TEST table will contain all six values from the `arr`.

So, instead of calling your procedure in each iteration, simply memorize values in an array then pass it to your procedure in one big call at the very end.